# How to change the integration measure between vectors and complex numbers?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, integration

When using $CP(1)$ representation, we will write the unit vector $\boldsymbol{n}$ as the the spinor form, i.e. complex number:
$$\boldsymbol{n}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}z_{1}^{\dagger} & z_{2}^{\dagger}\end{array}\right) \boldsymbol{\sigma}\left(\begin{array}{c}z_{1} \\ z_{2}\end{array}\right)$$
with the constraint
$$z_{1}^{\dagger} z_{1}+z_{2}^{\dagger} z_{2}=1$$
However, I am confused how to change integration measure when we use path integral. Namely, some reference says it is like:
$$\int d\boldsymbol{n} \delta({\boldsymbol{n}^2-1})\rightarrow \int \prod_{m=1,2}\frac{d \Re z_m d \Im z_m}{\pi}\delta(z_{1}^{\dagger} z_{1}+z_{2}^{\dagger} z_{2}=1)$$
I cannot understand how to obtain this relation. For example, I don't know how to write the Jacobian determinant since its form seems different from $du dv\rightarrow dxdy$ . Also, I also don't know why the constraint don't make any effect when we consider the measure?

Comment: Can you say which reference? Also, I believe you mean $z_1^{\dagger}z_1 + z_2^{\dagger} z_2 -1$ in the argument of the delta function as opposed to $z_1^{\dagger}z_1 + z_2^{\dagger} z_2 =1$. Also, can you include a definition of $\sigma$ ? Is it any specific pauli spin matrix or a linear combination? If it's the latter, is it normalized?